# how to write a sql query for getting this?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

i have two tables. and i want following desired  result.

## Table 1

```
id | salary

01 | 500

04 | 300

07 | 700
```

## Table 2

```
id | salary

02 | 300

05 | 800

06 | 700
```

## I want output like

```
id | salary

01 | 500

02 | 300

03 | <em>null</em>

04 | 300

05 | 800

06 | 700

07 | 700

08 | <em>null</em>

09 | <em>null</em>

10 | <em>null</em>
```

Comment: You can use `UNION`

Comment: You have tagged this `mysql` and `sql-server`. Which one is it?

Comment: @ta.speot.is any of them. but prefered is mysql.

Comment: With union we can't get null values for the missing elements. It will just merge both the tables. @anon

Comment: So you want null against missing IDs. Is there a limit to maximum number of IDs?

Comment: yes. there is limit in IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using **SQL Server**, then Probably this solution should work for you

```
;WITH CTE
AS(
    SELECT
        ID = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        Id = Id+1
        FROM CTE
            WHERE Id <  10
),C2
AS
(
    SELECT
        ID,
        Salary
        FROM YourTable1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        ID,
        Salary
        FROM YourTable2
)
SELECT
    CTE.ID,
    C2.Salary
    FROM CTE
        LEFT JOIN C2
            ON CTE.ID = C2.ID
```

Comment: how will it be written in MySQL?

Comment: MySql Does not support CTE, so you can't try this there.

Comment: but i want an alternative to write it in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution where I used a numbers table and created numbers with zero padding (better to use a SQL [pad zeros function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-pad-leading-zeros.aspx))

In fact your two tables where salary data is stored are same, and you only need a UNION or UNION ALL here
Below select simulates a solution like a UNION case here but if there are two entries one on each table for a id number like '01' then only first table salary is used. Please consider cases like this on your case.

```
SELECT
    RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',2) + Convert(varchar(2),Number),2) as id,
    coalesce(t1.salary,t2.salary) as salary
FROM master..spt_values num
LEFT JOIN [Table 1] as t1 on t1.id = RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',2) + Convert(varchar(2),num.Number),2)
LEFT JOIN [Table 2] as t2 on t2.id = RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',2) + Convert(varchar(2),num.Number),2)
WHERE 
    Type = 'P' and Number <= 10
ORDER BY Number
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server...This should help..You can replace 20 with the max number you need to generate.

```
;WITH SingleDigits(Number) AS
(
    SELECT Number
    FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8),
    (9), (0)) AS X(Number)
)
,Series AS
(
    SELECT (d1.Number+1) + (10*d2.Number) + (100*d3.Number) + (1000*d4.Number) Number
    from
    SingleDigits as d1,
    SingleDigits as d2,
    SingleDigits as d3,
    SingleDigits as d4
)
,CTE1 AS ( SELECT id, salary FROM Table1 UNION ALL SELECT id, Salary from table2 )
SELECT s.Number Id, c.salary FROM Series s 
LEFT JOIN  CTE1 c ON s.Number = c.Id
WHERE Number < 20
```